# Dynamically fill a list with key value pairs

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket, r5rs

I need to fill a list with pairs, for example: ((x 10)(z 5)).

My current method:

```
;;send the current list, and an id value pair
(define (setID idList ID VAL)

  (cond 
        ;;if the list is null, add the pair
        ((null? idList) (cons '(ID VAL) '()))    

        ;; if the ID already exists, overwrite it
        ((equal? ID (car(car idList)))  (cons '((cdr idList)) VAL))

        ;; continue the search
        (else  (setID (cdr idList) ID VAL))
  )
)
```

I realize I also need to use `cons` to keep the list in tact, but the first problem is that when I do something like `(setID z 5)`, the returned list is exactly: `((id val))`. Obviously, it needs to be `((z 10))`. Is there anyway to do such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three main problems with your code:

- In here: `(cons '(ID VAL) '()))` you're building a new pair with the value `(ID VAL)` - that is, the first element *is* the symbol `ID` and the second *is* the symbol `VAL`. That's not what you want, you want the *value* of `ID` and the *value* of `VAL`. Make sure you understand the way a `quote` works
- When you find an existing `ID` you have to cons the newly modified pair with the rest of the list
- And even if the current pair isn't the one we're looking for, we *also* have to `cons` it to the output. Remember: we're building the answer as we go traversing the list

This is what I mean:

```
;;send the current list, and an id value pair
(define (setID idList ID VAL)
  (cond 
    ;;if the list is null, add the pair
    ((null? idList) (cons (list ID VAL) '()))
    ;; if the ID already exists, overwrite it
    ((equal? ID (car (car idList))) (cons (list ID VAL) (cdr idList)))
    ;; continue the search
    (else (cons (car idList) (setID (cdr idList) ID VAL)))))
```

And don't forget that the list returned after executing this procedure is a *new* one, you have to store it somewhere or pass it along as a parameter if you want to keep adding elements to it - because the list originally received as parameter remains unmodified. Now the procedure works as expected:

```
(setID '() 'x 10)
=> '((x 10))

(setID '((x 10)) 'y 20)
=> '((x 10) (y 20))

(setID '((x 10) (y 20)) 'x 30)
=> '((x 30) (y 20))
```

Comment: Thank. You. So much. Just changed it to what you have, and the entire program started working properly. Thought I had a long way to go.

Comment: So glad to hear that! :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't re-invent the wheel, association lists are pretty common in scheme

Easiet thing here is the guard with a head tag. so that `((x 10)(z 5))` becomes `(*idList* (x 10)(z 5))`

```
;;send the current list, and an id value pair
(define (setID! idList ID VAL)
;;if a function mutates data end it with a bang
  (let ((ID-VAL (assoc ID (cdr idList)))) 
        ;;assoc returns #f if no match, with the ID-VAL pair if there is a match
        (if ID-VAL
            (set-car! (cdr ID-VAL) VAL)  
                     ;; if the ID already exists, overwrite it     
            (set-cdr! idList (cons (list ID VAL) (cdr idList)))))
                     ;;if ID into in assoc-list, add the pair
    idList)      ;;return the idList
```

Testing

```
(setID! '(*idList*) 'x 10)
;Value 3: (*idlist* (x 10))

(setID! '(*idlist* (x 10)) 'y 20)
;Value 4: (*idlist* (y 20) (x 10))

(setID! '(*idlist* (y 20) (x 10)) 'x 30)
;Value 9: (*idlist* (y 20) (x 30))
```

Comment: My current challenge does not allow me to use most of that code, but it is still a good answer, sorry I did not specify earlier. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Racket-y version of the answer from @WorBlux :

Your "`setID`" is essentially already defined in Racket under the name [`dict-set`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/dicts.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fdict..rkt%29._dict-set%29%29).

> ```
> (dict-set dict key v) → (and/c dict? immutable?)
>    dict : (and/c dict? immutable?)
>    key  : any/c
>    v    : any/c
> ```
>
> Functionally extends `dict` by mapping `key` to `v`, overwriting any existing mapping for `key`, and returning an extended dictionary. The update can fail with a `exn:fail:contract` exception if `dict` does not support functional extension or if `key` is not an allowed key for the dictionary.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> > (dict-set #hash() 'a "apple")
> '#hash((a . "apple"))
>
> > (dict-set #hash((a . "apple") (b . "beer")) 'b "banana")
> '#hash((b . "banana") (a . "apple"))
>
> > (dict-set '() 'a "apple")
> '((a . "apple"))
>
> > (dict-set '((a . "apple") (b . "beer")) 'b "banana")
> '((a . "apple") (b . "banana"))
> ```

See the last two examples above.

And of course you can use `dict-ref` and other functions to look up values by key, or map over them, and so on.

Note that `dict-set` is slightly different what you described because `assoc` (as used by `dict`) uses `(key . val)` not `(key val)`. In other words it uses `(cons key val)` not `(list key val)`. It's more efficient to store two items with `(cons a b)` than `(cons a (cons b '()))`.